# isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types error in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-rest-framework

I keep getting this error when using Django Rest Framework:

```
isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Here is my model:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    firstfield = models.ArrayModelField(models.FloatField())
    secondfield = models.ArrayModelField(models.FloatField())

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(mymodel, self).save(*args, using='mydb', **kwargs)
```

Here is what my data looks like:

```
id: 'some id here'
firstfield: ['somefloat', 'somefloat'], ['another float', 'another float'] ...
secondfield: ['somefloat', 'somefloat'], ['another float', 'another float'] ...
```

I think the problem is with my MongoDB data. Basically, `firstfield` and 'secondfield' are both lists, containing other lists, each one with two float numbers. Every advice to fix this is appreciated

Comment: You should use an `ListField`, *not* an `ArrayModelField`. An `ArrayModelField`, like the name suggests deals with storing model instances.

Comment: This is right! I'm getting a 'djongo.models' has no attribute 'ArrayField' error now, however

Comment: what if you use a `ListField`?

Comment: Yes! I did not know about it until you mentioned it, and it seems to be the way to go! Thank you @WillemVanOnsem!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on an [`ArrayModelField` [Djongo-doc]](https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/list-field/#arraymodelfield) says:

> With MongoDB there can be an **array of embedded documents** inside the parent document. You can create an embed **array/list of models inside the parent model** and store it directly into MongoDB.

So this is used to store a collection of model objects, not floats, etc. You can use a [**`ListField`** [Djongo-doc]](https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/mongodb-field-reference/#listfield) for that.